# What's the best storage strategy for saving text mining statistics?

Tags: database, analytics, text-mining, nosql

I am working on a web application that analyzes articles on the web for their content. The goal is to identify and categorize terms within these articles, check whether these are part of a given list of terms and count how often they appear.

Entities include:

- Articles (URL, date, short description, content)
- Terms (name, type, frequency)
- List(name, list of terms)

Example queries would include:

- list all terms of a certain type and count their frequency over all articles
- for a given term, return the article where this term occurs most often

Considering that there might be a few thousand terms per article and thousands of articles, how would you store the data?

Does a normalized relational database make sense? Should I denormalize or use a NoSQL database?

Answer (score 1):

A normalised relational database (RDBMS) makes always sense to me. The normalisation gives you improvements in terms of consistency and speed on the most frequent queries.

You can also consider NoSQL solutions in case your entities are simple (id and a bunch of attributes) therefore you don't really need the power of a RDBMS.

In your case, I would go for a well designed, once for all, RDBMS solution. MySQL would be more than perfect for the job.